# How to perform an upward wall slide?

Tags: super-meat-boy

Every once in a while, when trying to wall jump, Meat Boy does an upward wall-slide instead of another jump. Is that a kind of "bug" or is it possible to perform an upward slide while sliding?

I guess it depends on the right timing you press <kbd>A</kbd> while approaching the wall, but I'm not sure.

And no, I **don't** mean the classic wall sliding that you get from the vertical momemtum of a normal jump.

Does anybody can explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known glitch.

From http://smb.thecybershadow.net/Bugs_and_problems

> Inability to wall jump under certain circumstances
>
> As shown in this video, you can sometimes end up wall jumping directly up the wall you're currently sliding on. This also happens when at the bottom of a vertical conveyor belt pushing you downwards.

The video in question is this one:

As for how to reproduce the glitch, it seems it's not consistent and is related to pressing jump in a particular frame just before touching the wall, as you described

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate...